# SAP HANA SQL query to connect to system (database)?

Tags: hana

I'm wondering if there is a SQL console query to connect to your system(database)?
[image]

If you look at the image, let's say I don't want to click on the upper right icon and select a connection, and on the SQL console the first line is simulating a connection to the selected system (`connect database P194xxxxx`), then `set schema` and then run a simple `select` query. But obviously the first line will not work and I'm wondering if there's some query that can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such functionality available.
The SQL console does not allow to switch connections via command text.